# How can I do a responsive absolute positioning?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a banner that has two buttons on it:

```css
.banner {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: -4%;
}

.banner img {
  width: 100%;
  /*image is 1232x317 by default and defines the size of the banner*/
}

.banner-buttons {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-left: 6.2%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
}

.banner button {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 200%;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5px 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/300">
  <div class="banner-buttons">
    <button>Assistir</button>
    <button>Mais Informações</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

but the problem is, the height of the buttons change based on the viewport, destroying the banner, how can I position it without ruining it?

Comment: Did you perhaps mean "[responsive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Responsive_Design)" and not "[responsible](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/responsible)"?

Comment: *"without ruining it"* does not explain what's the issue and the desired.

Comment: 1- I did mean "responsive", sorry for that. 2- the problem I'm facing is that the div with the buttons is not respecting the parent div, but respecting the page instead,  causing it to be displayed at unintended places based on the viewport.

Comment: Absolute positioning often causes more problems than it solves. I'd stick to flex and proportionate padding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually what solved for me was adding `position: relative` to `.banner`, now the buttons are displayed at the exact same position at every screen size.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally avoid absolute positioning and use background image to create the layers.

You can set a min height on your banner if you desire.

I would also use `em` and `media queries` to reduce the font size when the screen resolution is smaller.

```css
.banner {
  background:url(https://picsum.photos/1200/300);
  padding:10px;  
}

.banner-buttons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items: center;
}

.banner button {
  font-size: 2em;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <div class="banner-buttons">
    <button>Assistir</button>
    <button>Mais Informações</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: using background image actually helps with the buttons positioning, but creates a problem with the height of the image, causing it to cut vertically on large monitors. For some reason, if I dont define a height it is rendered with height of 0

Comment: @JuanEliasdaCunha It's flex, it's supposed to be the height of its contents. I have a large monitor and it looks fine to me. You need to be clearer in your question what you want to achieve.